# Is it possible to emulate processor cores or threads to the operation system?

Tags: multithreading, cpu

First, let me say that:

- I know it wont get me more performance
- In fact, i know it'll get me less performance, if it is possible at all!

Basically, i want the more Threads as possible on a single machine!
I want the operation system to recognize them all, and a want a specific application to run scripts on the single threads generated... (the application is not mine, so i can't edit it directly)

1st - Is it possible?
2nd - how?

Answer (score 2):

You can't change other programs, unless you have their source code or are willing to go to great lengths of disassembling it and then monkey patching the things together that you need, at which point it might just be better to write it from scratch.

Also, keep in mind that applications not specifically designed to deal with multithreading, are not only not likely to gain much or any performance from it, it will also lead to a lot of bugs and problems due to timing and atomicity issues.

In theory you can spin up as many threads as the OS lets you, and the OS will all allow them to run on the CPU. That's one of the fundamental aspects of the underlying kernel of any modern OS after all. But you can't tell the OS to just spin up more threads for a specific program, what you can do is give it a higher priority so that the existing threads the program spins up get more time on the CPU. But that's no longer a programming issue but how to use the OS you are working with.

Comment: i see...
well, i don't really care about the performance, has i mentioned before... all the tech details, not a problem... i just want to "make new threads pop up!"... so, when i run this app, it shows me more threads available!
Do you know a way to make the OS recognize more threads then?

Comment: @JosEvora No, you can't tell the OS to spin up more threads for the process than it requests. How would that even work? What would these threads even execute? The OS can't guess these things.

Comment: @JosEvora What are you actually trying to achieve here though? Why do you need more threads anyways? As you've pointed out for yourself, it will be decremental to performance, and as I said, it will lead to bugs and crashes all over the place if the program wasn't designed to be run on multiple threads

Comment: well, the program uses part of the threads processing power... (10%)
it 'borrows' my cpu to a 3rd part company, and that company pays me on THE NUMBER OF THREADS RUNNING!!! get it?...
My point is to double the 10% to 20%, and double the recognized threads as well... so, in theory, i'll keep the performance of the program, per Thread, and i'll double my possible gain...

Comment: I have a dedicated machine, btw... so, in theory, i can use up to 100%  of it... the more the better!